# Android runs very slow with Genymotion

Tags: android, appium, genymotion

Recently I started to use Appium with Android driver.
Before that I've used Appium for IOS automation (real device / simulator) and it works great.

With android , I've noticed that things are not so smooth ... the execution of the test on Genymotion emulator takes a lot of time , sometimes the appium server hardly responding until it being restarted ...

While I'm executing the same test on real device , it runs much faster.

I'm using appium 1.4.1 and java_client 3.1.0
the operating system is IOS

tested app runs on API 19+
Genymotion ver 2.5.2 (nexus 5 device)
the emulator has 4 CPU + 2GB ram

the main selector for element searching is contentDescription and sometimes elemnt's id

the slowness I'm trying to describe is to find element by contentDesc / id takes 8-15 sec ... to get text from it additional 10 sec...

as it mentioned , in real device it's much faster
I definitely would use real device ,but the problem is a connection to internal assets which cannot be accessed from real device.

Any idea how to improve Android execution with Genymotion ?

Thanks

Comment: android studio (or) eclipse ? If studio means you need to improve your Gredle

Comment: It's android studio,  what do you mean by improve gradle? I'm building the automation suite and not the app itself

Comment: see my answer here , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32068389/3983054

Comment: I've read the answer , just cant understand how does it being related to Appium framework ?

Comment: sorry, that answer is for reducing the build time in android studio, Actually i am completely dumb in the usage of genymotion. but this links may help you http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/  and http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Speedup-Android-development-testing-using-Genymotion-emulator

Comment: the thing is , my issue it's not with app building time , but with the test execution by using Appium framework and genymotion emulator ...

Comment: Yeah. now i got it, that will be purely depend on the genymotion factors such as available space, network speed so so

Comment: not sure , I set up a strong "device" Geny motion machine got 4 CPU + 4GB ram, and still , it takes ages to appium to look after the elements within the app