# why Android Studio build process cost too long time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

started Building a basic Hello World App in Android Studio v 1.2.1

Gradle Build is taking too much time for building and running the app.

Somebody can tell why ,3q

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826562/1770868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Gradle need to download stuffs on first build, so your internet connection
   might affect the build time
2. Building your project needs computer's memory (RAM), watch your RAM
   usage. Might be your OS decide to user your page file, which is bad.
   Increase your RAM