# Android Studio makes my devices very slow after some running

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, device

I started to have this issue after migrate from eclipse to AS. When i run one app for the first time, it's running normally....but after 5 ~ 10 run...my device stop to respond to any touch/button press (only hold the power works)...and even removing the USB, my device run any app very very slow.

I already tried this topics:

http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html

[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

i put this on manifest

```
android:vmSafeMode="true"
```

and no one works. Anyone knows why it happens?