# Does installing all the packages in android studio slows it down?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install all the packages on android Studio,will doing that slows android studio?

Comment: What do you mean by all the packages?

Comment: I mean all the packages available on Android SDK

Comment: No. Downloading packages of Android SDK won't slow down your android studio. To get your android studio perform faster please follow this SO question. I've an answer here that worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31633775/3145960

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can only ask programming based question!! Opinions are not recommended on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sibidharan, IDE related questions are allowed, and this was a yes/no question, no opinion involved

Comment: @Gavriel Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by installing "all the packages" you mean downloading all the SDK versions, emulators, etc. No downloading them won't slow you down, only the emulators that are running use your CPU, RAM.