# Is there a way to see what is taking gradle build so long?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio and my builds are taking 3-4 minutes every time. Is there a way to what is taking too long?

Thanks.

Comment: i think there are parameters you can add to the gradle command, using the studio. like `-info` and `-debug`, this will show detailed log, maybe it can help

Comment: I have experienced aggravating gradle performance problems and for me it turned out to be gradle/Android Studio taking a long time to download software update files from the internet.  I found this problem by running "Wireshark" in the background and watching HTTP traffic going to URLs that were clearly relating to gradle's build process.  So that might be something you could try.

Comment: I just change 1 line of code, click run button and wait 3-4 minutes each time. I build with run button, no command line, so how do i see -info now?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason for this issue,

Please check [Gradle taking long time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500539/2826147) for more detail.

Some of reasons are

- Dependencies
- Code stucture

Comment: I am using google cloud messaging api, but is it normal time for a build ?

Comment: Yes, it is normal to that it is taking time to build for first time but while on next time it should take less time than first one. take several steps that are described in my answer link and it will decrease time to build such as code optimization @Jdodo

Comment: check this link to reduce build time http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/ @Jdodo

Comment: I understand it should take long first time, however that is not the case here. I build it in 4 minutes run it, then change 1 line of code, and still wait 4 minutes.

Comment: that are many reasons for that some of them described in answer and update your studio to latest will also make some difference

Comment: did you get your or still in confusion @Jdodo