# android studio project refreshing working slowly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i downloaded lates android studio and successfully instaled.now i try to import my project in android studio.when i importing it i have a problemm.i have this screen and refreshing gradly project working slowly

[image]

i don't know what is a wrong in my android studio.
p.s
my project perect working another pc,i mean another android studio
if anyone knows solution please help me
this is a basic information about my computer

[image]
thanks everyone

Comment: [Basic System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements)

Comment: @Pratik Butani i updated  second image please see it

Comment: refer this and follow first answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips