# Why does Android Studio build the entire project after a single letter change and Run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Why does Android Studio build the entire project after a single letter change and Run?

Lets say I have the magic number 42 in a class, and I change it to 43. I had just run the project, and now I click Run again.. another 2 minutes of waiting!!!

Sometimes I even run the same thing twice in a row without changes at all and it builds the entire thing from scratch anew.

Is there a way to configure Gradle to behave a bit smarter?

Comment: In my case, I noticed that it was taking too much time at ZipAlign proccess. So, I disable it during debug compilation by adding: "zipAlignEnabled false" in my build.gradle. When build, open gradle console (right-bottom edge) and observe which proccess is taking too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is **Android Studio 2.0**. It has *"Instant Run"* feature. It uploads app instantly. Android Studio 2.0 is in beta channel right now.
[You can download it from here.](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0-preview)

And about instant run feature you can find detailed article [here.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

If you don't want to use beta version, another solution could be setting daemon true. [You can see how too set gradle daemon true in this link.](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/)

Hope these will work for you :)

Comment: thanks, when will 2.0 be officially stable and ready for use? And do you know why does Gradle build the whole thing from scratch every time?

Comment: Im going to test the second suggestion these days

Comment: I don't know when it will release in stable channel actually. But I believe it will be soon. I don't know why gradle does this actually but sometimes it drives me crazy too. About faster gradle there are lots of articles and questions in web. I can suggest this question especially. Answers are really usefull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips[link]

Comment: Android studio is in stable channel for your information :)