# Gradle build taking too long

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:assembleDebug]
>
> Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating
>   feature. Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>   :app:clean :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareAsiaIvityAndroidMarqueeview115Library
>   :app:prepareComAndraskindlerParallaxviewpagerParallaxviewpager031Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
>   :app:prepareComGithubTecheryProgresshintLibrary023Library
>   :app:prepareComGithubTecheryProgresshintLibraryAddition023Library
>   :app:prepareComH6ah4iAndroidWidgetVerticalseekbarVerticalseekbar051Library
>   :app:prepareComOgaclejapanSmarttablayoutLibrary160Library
>   :app:prepareComToxicBakeryViewpagerTransformsViewPagerTransforms1232Library
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeDebugShaders :app:compileDebugShaders
>   :app:generateDebugAssets :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources :app:processDebugManifest
>   :app:processDebugResources :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidexInstrumentation101Library
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
>   :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not
>   incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources
>   :app:buildInfoDebugLoader :app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>   :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   :app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
>   :app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
>   :app:incrementalDebugTasks :app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
>   :app:fastDeployDebugExtractor :app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
>   :app:coldswapKickerDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug To run dex in process, the Gradle
>   daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 11833 MB.
>   For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle
>   daemon to more than 13312 MB. To do this set
>   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx13312M in the project gradle.properties. For
>   more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
>   :app:validateDebugSigning :app:packageDebug :app:zipalignDebug
>   :app:fullDebugBuildInfoGenerator :app:assembleDebug
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 7 mins 41.523 secs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips

Comment: My problem is solved.It was taking time because i have ubuntu and i was opening and running my project from external ntfs hard drive.I reformatted it as ext4 and followed the given post which reduced the **build time** to **2 sec** from 7 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved.It was taking time because i have ubuntu and i was opening and running my project from external ntfs hard drive.I reformatted it as ext4 and followed the post given in comment section by Amit Vaghela , which reduced the build time from 7 min to 2 sec.

This is the link given by 'Amit Vaghela':

[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

Answer (score 2):

> The default Gradle Daemon VM memory allocation is 1 gigabyte — which is insufficient to support dexInProcess, so to take advantage you’ll need to set it to at least 2 gigabytes.

One thing you could do to speed up your builds is to increase the Gradle Daemon VM memory allocation.

In `gradle.properties` add the line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m`.

Good read about Android Studio 2.1 feature *Dex In Process*:

https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e?_utm_source=1-2-2#.g4ba8piij

And also check out the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SY5nkNVUn0

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: absolutely true. Thanks for correcting me, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make your gradle offline.

> Goto File -> Settings search for gradle and checked offline work .

[image]

Comment: That's hardly a solution considering you will need it to go online at times

Comment: My problem is solved.It was taking time because i have ubuntu and i was opening and running my project from external ntfs hard drive.I reformatted it as ext4 and followed the post given in comment section by  **Amit Vaghela** , which reduced the build time from 7 min to **2 sec**