# Android Studio: Slow build time: Settings in Preferences does NOT seem to save?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is in relation to rather slow build times I recently had. I used to have ~1 minute build times but now I'm getting ~4 minute ones. Upon looking around on how to reduce build times, I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500539/1374416) and I did everything that that answer advised. I also turned on "Offline Mode" for my Gradle Settings. I tried it and the build time finished under 10 seconds. However, when I started to work again and when I built the project again, it didn't seem to work any more -- I was back to my 4 minute build times.

I don't know how or why this is the case. It seems that the settings only worked *once* then they seemed to be discarded thereon out.

I am currently using Android Studio 2.1.2.

### Edit

I ran the wrong command, here's a proper one:

I ran the command in the comments below, it gave this report:

And it's an awful long time to configure the project.

[image]

Comment: Could you run `./gradlew :android:assembleDebug --dry-run --profile` and then open generated report? the report filename will be similar to this; `build/reports/profile/profile-2016-02-02-15-39-17.html` This could give useful information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Youngjae I updated my question.

Comment: then, it would be good to see in `Task Execution` tab.

Comment: @Youngjae there wasn't actually anything in the Task Execution Tab. No tasks were listed and it totalled off at 0s.

Comment: hmmm.......I hardly understand why it is.

Comment: @Youngjae sorry about that, I realized that I ran the wrong command. I updated my post.