# Change in Android Studio Performance

Tags: android

Android Studio worked normally until recently. Then overnight response to any action , mouse clicks to select an object, or attempts to scroll thru a list of classes, any edit of source code resulted in a 2 to 5 second delay. All other actions on my pc were normal. No response problems.
Can anyone suggest a cause.

Comment: What is ur AS version?\

Comment: This question would have been suited for Android Studio forum or IntelliJ forum. There could be a possibility that it is a product defect.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826562/1770868