# Android Studio gradle sync is slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Everytime I sync my gradle files on any of my projects, it takes 10-15 minutes stucked in this step: 
Gradle: Resolve artifact multidex-instrumentation.aar (com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1)

I've tried deleting .gradle folder, reseting caches, offline mode, memory size... nothing works.

If I delete the m2repository and download it again, this specific folder (multidex-instrumentation/1.0.1) is downloaded normally, but always takes forever stucked on the same step.

Any clue?

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name "crashlytics"
            url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)