# How to improve Android Studio 3.0 build time?

Tags: java, android, performance, gradle, build

```
Android Studio 3.0
MacBook Pro 2.5 GHz i7, 16GB Ram, 500 GB SSD.
```

My build time takes anywhere from `~45 seconds`, `~2minutes`, `~5minutes`.  I think I get 5 minutes after a clean/build, 2 minutes after changing code, and 45 seconds with no code changes.

1. What hardware improvements would have most impact on android build times?  Is it mostly CPU constrained, disk, memory?
2. What build times do other Android people see for their projects?  Is 2 minutes normal, slow or fast?
3. Are there any build tricks that can improve the time?  I've reviewed articles to improve performance and tried suggestions but if anyone knows some pitfalls I might have run into that would be great.

-Thanks!!

Comment: Go on the Medium.com page, search specific phrase and you'll find many good examples how to optimise your project or even the gradle at all.

Comment: did you increase ram for android studio??@CodeSmith

Comment: i have the same problem after i used 4g for android studio it worked fast

Comment: I had not increase Android Studio memory usage, thank you for the tip!  Tried it and think I see some improvement, will update times if it's looking better.

Comment: After increasing memory usage got build times down to ~3m45s, ~1m, ~30sec.  Good gains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this post [Android Studio is slower than eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips) and found a suggestion to check anti-virus. Created an exception on my corporate AV scanner for my project files and Android Studio folder and that seems to have brought my build times down significantly.  Previous 5min clean/build now takes 1 min, code change build of 45 sec is down to 20 sec.