# How to properly deal with class dependencies to utilize incremental compilation in Java/Android with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.0, incremental-compiler

I improved our build system and activated incremental builds and compilation as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585625/android-studio-slow-incremental-build) question. To my disappointment, incremental compilation didn't improve build times as much as I expected from reading [Gradles blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance).

After some investigation, I realized that the issue is that even though I only add a comment to a small class somewhere deep in the app apparently almost the whole codebase is rebuilt. In fact, it doesn't really matter which class I touch, Gradles `--debug` output reveals that it basically always recompiles 476 classes.

> Incremental compilation of 476 classes completed in 12.51 secs.

While I understand that `public static` constants in the changed file trigger a full recompilation (which is only slightly slower), I don't understand how to properly break up class dependencies so that incremental compilation actually works. What are the exact rules to determine class dependencies that affect incremental compilation? I could read about some examples [here](https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance), but it doesn't appear to apply to our (fairly standard) project at all.

Some of my own testings yielded the following:

```
// One of my main classes that has lots of class dependencies
public class A{
   public void foo() {
       // This line produces a dependency between A and B. So changing just
       // a comment in B triggers recompilation of all classes attached to A
       B b1 = new B(); 


   }
}

// A small helper class that I want to change
public class B {
   public void bar() {
       // This line does not create a dependency, so B can still be compiled by
       // itself. But usually, that's not the "common" direction you have.
       A a1 = new A();
       // I make the change here and then trigger a new build
   }
}
```

Why does A need recompilation when an implementation detail, but not the interface of B changed?

I also tried "hiding" B behind an interface C. I thought that would be the proper (even though often times very cumbersome) way to break up the dependencies. But it turns out it didn't help at all.

```
public class A{
   public void foo() {
       C c1 = C.cFactory();
   }
}

public class B implements C {
   public void bar() {
       // I make the change here and then trigger a new build
   }
}

public interface C {
   void bar();

   public static C cFactory() {
       return new B();
   }
}
```

It appears to me that we have this big dependency blob and I am uncertain this could reasonably be changed even though I would argue we have a reasonably designed codebase. Are there best practices, guidelines or design patterns that are common among Android developers that would effectively improve incremental compilations?

I do wonder whether others have the same problem as we do and if not what did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in fact that all our classes are part of a big dependency graph. This shows in the quote

> Incremental compilation of 476 classes completed in 12.51 secs.

Basically, any class I touch causes a recompilation of 476 classes. In our particular case, this is caused by two patterns. We use Explicit Intents in Android, [which I am not sure how to better handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637546/how-to-avoid-a-class-dependency-monolith-using-intents-in-android). Additionally, we use Dagger in such a way, that we connected all classes in a circle.

Concerning the interface problematic I made a rather obvious mistake with implementing the `cFactory()`. As this creates a class dependency from `C` to `B` and thus transitively from `A` to `C`.

The following snippet breaks the dependency from `A` to `B` but creates one from `B` to `A`.

```
public class A{
   public static void foo(C input) {
       input.foo();
   }
}

public class B implements C {
   public void bar() {
       // I make the change here and then trigger a new build
       A.foo(this);
   }
}

public interface C {
   void bar();
}
```